# How to set default value of Select element in Material Tailwind?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, tailwind-css

I have a component Select with 3 options, but I need to set a default value when rendering the component, the tailwind material Option component does not support the selected tag.

How can I set a default value in the Select component?

```
<Select label="Type Product">
     <Option>Crédito</Option>
     <Option>Rotativo</Option>
     <Option>Renting</Option>
</Select>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the official [document](https://www.material-tailwind.com/docs/react/props/select) of this library also does not provide clear instructions on default value for this component.

While not ideal, I tried to implement it by setting a matching `value` on both `Select` and `Option` which could possibly work as a default value, especially if this is to be used as a controlled component. Here is a basic live demo of the test on: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-hdyhui?file=src/App.jsx).

Example:

```
//  Setting Option with value of "3" as the default value for Select

<Select value={"3"} label="Select an option">
  {["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"].map((item) => {
    return <Option key={item} value={item}>{`Option ${item}`}</Option>;
  })}
</Select>
```

Comment: It gives an error: You provided a `value` prop to a select component without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only select. If the field should be mutable use `onChange` handler with `value` together.

Answer (score 0):

It says in the documentation that *value* accepts only string and you have to pass string as a value and iterate an array of **string**.

Probably in your case, you recieved an array of **objects** and tried to iterate inside  ...  at the same time gave a default value as a string, which causes a chaos inside the  component.

This is a bug you should create a pull request from the repo.